# How do I search user input for specific characters?

Tags: c#, console, contains

New to C#, but I love it! I used to use java and still do sometimes, but C# in Visual Studio is amazing.

Now the business...

I want to create a console application that prints messages to the console whenever the user inputs a sentence containing either a T, a t(lower case) or a question mark (?)

I have tried the below, but I have not been successful. It must look like kindergarten scrawl to some of you.

Someone please help me. I thank you in advance!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type a sentence without using the letter T or a question mark.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        string userValue;
        userValue = Console.ReadLine();


        if(userValue.Contains("T"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        }
        else if(userValue.Contains("t"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
            else if (userValue.Contains("?"));
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```
if(userValue.Contains("T") ||userValue.Contains("t") ||userValue.Contains("?"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right track, thanks. I am currently looking for a way to keep the program running if the user does not enter a T or a t or a ? But WOW this was fast. Thanks again.

Comment: Done. Another issue I'm having, as a rookie! Is how to keep the program open while the user still wants to input sentences. Maybe you can help? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. While (true) loop wrapped around my code.

Answer (score 0):

If the questionmark has to be at the end try using userValue.endWith("?") or if you want to check if the input is only the questionmark try userValue == "?"

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check for T, t or ?, try this.

```
if((userValue.Contains("T") || if(userValue.Contains("t") || (userValue.Contains("?"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(userValue);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, going to definitely try this one too. When I get back in today.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you don't need that many `Console.ReadLine()` in your code.
If you want to ask user once, the solution could be something like:

```
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.WriteLine("Type a sentence without using the letter T or a question mark.");
  String userValue = Console.ReadLine();

  if (userValue.Contains('T')) 
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains 'T'");
  else if (userValue.Contains('t')) 
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains 't'");
  else if (userValue.Contains('?')) 
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains '?'");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Valid, doesn't contain 'T', 't', '?'");
}
...
```

If you want to ask user inputing a value until (s)he puts a valid one:

```
...
static void Main(string[] args) {
  String userValue;

  // If you want to ask user once only, uncomment this line, otherwise comment it out  

  // Console.WriteLine("Type a sentence without using the letter T or a question 

  while (true) {
    // If you want to ask user any time he/she puts wrong sentence, uncomment this line, otherwise comment it out  
    Console.WriteLine("Type a sentence without using the letter T or a question mark.");
    userValue = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userValue.Contains('T')) 
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains 'T'");
    else if (userValue.Contains('t')) 
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains 't'");
    else if (userValue.Contains('?')) 
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid, contains '?'");
    else
      break;       
  }

  Console.WriteLine("Valid, doesn't contain 'T', 't', '?'");
}
...
```

Comment: This looks like it it will work. I will update you when I try it later. Thanks.

Comment: using your first example, how do I keep the program open and active while the user still wants to input sentences?

Comment: Nevermind. I just used the while (true) loop around my code. Duh. Simple.